# TypeError variable is not defined even though i defined it

Tags: javascript

So i was making a game in Javascript it involves drawing cards from a "Deck"
I used this code but got the error "TypeError: card_name is not defined"

```js
const draw_card = () => {
  let drawn_times = 0;
  let drawn_card = Math.round(Math.random() * 52);
  let card_name = cards[drawn_card];

  while (true) {
    for (i in cards_drawn) {
        if (i == card_name[0]) {
            drawn_times ++;
        }
    }

    if (!(drawn_times > decks)) {
        cards_drawn.push(card_name[0])
        break;
    }

    drawn_card = Math.round(Math.random() * 52);
    card_name = cards[drawn_card];
  }

  return card_name;
}

draw_card();
```

I cant seem to find why this keeps happening can anyone spot anything i could of missed

please do note the cards_drawn varible is a empty array and the cards variable is a array of 52 card names with there values like ["2 of clubs", 2]

Comment: Neither `cards`, `i`, `cards_drawn` nor `deck` is defined in the code you posted. Please add their declarations to make a [mcve] that produces the error you are describing.

Comment: `Math.round(Math.random() * 52)` can produce 52, which is out of the range of your array. You probably want `Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)`

Comment: Please post a complete example that actually generates the error you see. We can't verify your question as your code is incomplete so that it generates other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Where you declare variable "cards"?
The problem is in line 4, `let card_name = cards[drawn_card];` you try to get a specific elements from variable "cards" which seems not to exist.

Comment: It was defined like "const cards = [["ace of diamonds", 1, 11"], [another card]]" at the beginning of the script file